# Avoid memory allocation of bad bytes in RAM using Windows XP 32

Tags: windows-xp, memory-management

I have two bad bytes in RAM: one at 0x6d8cdf00 and other at 0x6d8cdf04. I would like to ask Windows XP 32 to do not allocate memory over these 2 bytes, or allocate these bytes at boot time and do not allow them to be freed or moved. Do you know how to do that? Is it possible to write a code in kernel mode in order to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Lucas.

P.S.: yes, I tried to change the memory card, but the problem remains at same address, and I can´t change the main board for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you really need to go and get the *hardware* fixed. Every other option is a crapshoot with your valuable data.

Fixing it is a much better alternative than the kernel-level hoops you're going to have to jump through to get this to work even if it's possible, especially since Windows isn't like Linux - you can't just recompile the kernel.